# Questionable hyperlinks in example newsletter

Tags: discussion, newsletter

Every so often Stack Overflow encourages me to sign-up for their newsletter, a great feature here is to show an example newsletter.
After some time I finally became interested in what this newsletter had to offer and thus wanted to check the preview, which can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/newsletter/preview).

When viewing this I became intrigued by the footer links

[image: Example newsletter preview footer]

As it stands the "Unsubscribe from this newsletter" link links to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/newsletters/unsubscribe?id={{stackmail.secure_id}}&auth={{stackmail.secure_hmac}}` (exact url).
Which seems odd but the "Edit email settings" link seems even stranger, this link links to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY`.

Why is one of the links using raw parameters and the other linked to the most amazing youtube video ever?

The last link does do it job and just links to meta

Comment: Nick Craver [redirects some URL's to 10-hours-of-fun videos](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/c9458f2e007e9df2bdf03f8a02af1d13). I'm guessing they accidentally used one of the redirecting links in the newsletter.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I wouldn't say this is accidental, i'd say this is by design as this is the preview and not the actual newsletter

Comment: Why do you consider that newsletter link "odd", this is a preview.

Comment: Suggested title: *Why do hyperlinks in the example newsletter contain {{parameters}} and 10 hour memes?*

Comment: Related issue: Visiting [`https://stackoverflow.com/index.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/index.php) redirected me to a removed video [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozPPwl53c_4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozPPwl53c_4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick Craver [redirects some URL's to 10-hours-of-fun videos](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/c9458f2e007e9df2bdf03f8a02af1d13).

The pages that are normally redirected are the URL's used for WordPress sites. Some of the people who try to hack Stack Exchange sites, have failed to do their homework, and simply try the usual vulnerabilities of WordPress sites. (If they'd done their homework, they'd know that SO is built on ASP.Net, and that [one of its founders hated PHP passionately....](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/))

Apparently some of the redirecting links ended up in the newsletter preview, where they are used as sample links. As George points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363424/questionable-hyperlinks-in-example-newsletter?noredirect=1#comment558047_363424), this may be intentional - since it is a preview, not the actual newsletter.